# variable substitution in a Kubernetes YAML file

Tags: kubernetes, skaffold

I have a `deployments.yaml` file and for a hostpath in my spec I am doing something like this:

```yaml
    spec:
      volumes:
        - name: fe-source
          hostPath:
            path: /home/myname/src/TargetDirectory
```

notice here that the path mounted is an absolute path starting from my root folder all the way to my target directory. Now if I was developing solo, this would be just fine, I guess but the goal here is to collaborate with other devs and it would make much more sense to use a relative path. Something to the effect of

```yaml
spec:
  volumes:
    - name: fe-source
      hostPath:
        path: ../../../src/TargetDirectory
```

however, it appears that relative paths are not supported. I was wondering if there was a way to maybe incorporate an environment variable such `${PWD}` so that no matter which dev is working locally, they could just clone the repo and start as opposed to having to change that out for each dev

Comment: Since Kubernetes is a clustered environment, this will look for a `/home/myname` directory on whichever node the pod happens to be scheduled on; this doesn't really make sense.  Similarly, there's no particular notion of "current directory" or "developer environment", since the design goal is that a pod could be scheduled anywhere on a distributed cluster of disposable systems.  I'd try to avoid developing directly in a Kubernetes environment since its setup is so different from a local-developer setup.

Comment: So essentially there really isnt a work around for this sort of issue, even through a solution like helm charts?

Comment: @proverbialTurdNugget : Is your issue resolved? If yes, can you provide the resolution steps you have followed and provide it as an answer for the greater visibility of the community.

Comment: Hey @HemanthKumar unfortunately I don't have a solution yet to this problem